# Calculate the area of the ellipsoid obtained from ellipse $\frac {x^{2}}{2}+y^{2} = 1$ rotated around the $x$-axis

Tags: calculus, integration, conic-sections, area, ellipsoids

So we are about to calculate the area of the ellipsoid around the $x$-axis.

$$ \frac {x^{2}}{2}+y^{2} = 1 \implies x=\sqrt{2-y^{2}}$$

We are squaring it so the sign shouldn't matter.

I was thinking of it may be easier to solve for $x$ and then set up a integration, with the integration from $-1$ to $1$. And use :

$$ 2\pi\int_{-1}^{1} f(y) \sqrt{1+f'(y)^{2}} dy  $$

I also tried with solving for $y$, but got a very complicated integral. Or maybe I have done errors down the way?

Now I have solved for y instead and got the integral:

$$\pi\ \int_{-\sqrt{2}}^{\sqrt{2}} \sqrt{4-x^{2}} dx = 2\pi\ \int_0^{\sqrt{2}} \sqrt{4-x^{2}} dx $$

I have no idea how to solve this or how I should proceed, variable change? Partial integration? Fill me in...

Comment: If you want to find the volume of the solid generated by revolving the region inside the ellipse about the x-axis, you can use $V=\int_{a}^{b}\pi y^2 dx$

Comment: Yes, i know but I need the area. And I think the one I have written is the right one.

Comment: If you want to find the area enclosed by the ellipse, you can use $A=\int_{0}^{\sqrt{2}}4\sqrt{1-\frac{x^2}{2}}dx$.

Comment: Except you want $x=\sqrt{2-2y^2}$.  And probably you want to solve for $y$ to set up the integral.

Comment: The area, and the integral, can be found on Wikipedia: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ellipse#Area

Comment: @AndréNicolas I am trying to, but got a even worse integral now as you can see above I have made some progress. But need some help there :/

Comment: for the last integral you just added follow the trig substitution: if you have $\sqrt{a^2-x^2}$ substitute $x=a\sin(t)$.

Comment: At first glance, this does not look like a valid method of calculating area. Are you sure it’s right?

Comment: Question about the same ellipsoid: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1163540/surface-area-of-ellipsoid

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am assuming that you want to find the area of the surface generated by revolving the ellipse $\frac{x^2}{2}+y^2=1$ about the x-axis.  In that case,

Then $y^2=1-\frac{x^2}{2}=\frac{2-x^2}{2}$, so $y=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\sqrt{2-x^2}$ on the top half of the ellipse; and

$S=\int_{-\sqrt{2}}^{\sqrt{2}}2\pi y\sqrt{1+(\frac{dy}{dx})^2}\;dx=\int_{-\sqrt{2}}^{\sqrt{2}}2\pi\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\sqrt{2-x^2}\right)\sqrt{1+\frac{x^2}{2(2-x^2)}}\;dx$

$\;\;\;=2\int_{0}^{\sqrt{2}}2\pi\frac{\sqrt{2-x^2}}{\sqrt{2}}\frac{\sqrt{4-x^2}}{\sqrt{2}\sqrt{2-x^2}}dx = 2\pi\int_{0}^{\sqrt{2}}\sqrt{4-x^2}dx$.

Now let $x=2\sin\theta$ and $dx=2\cos\theta d\theta$ to get

$S=2\pi\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{4}}2\cos\theta\cdot 2\cos\theta d\theta=8\pi\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{4}}\cos^{2}\theta d\theta=8\pi\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{4}}\frac{1}{2}(1+\cos 2\theta)d\theta$

$=4\pi\left[\theta+\frac{1}{2}\sin2\theta\right]_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{4}}=4\pi\left(\frac{\pi}{4}+\frac{1}{2}\right)=\pi^{2}+2\pi$.

Answer (score 1):

Using the method of disks($V=π\int_{\alpha}^{\beta} f^2(x) dx$);
The function $y=\sqrt{\frac{2-x^2}{2}}$ has two distinct real roots $(\alpha,\beta)=(-\sqrt{2},\sqrt{2})$ and the solid of revolution of this half-elipsoid will have the same volume with the revolution of the whole ellipsoid as the whole elipsoid will just mark the solid of revolution's boundary one more time(symmetric), without doubling it's volume. So;

$π\int_{-\sqrt{2}}^{\sqrt{2}} (\sqrt{\frac{2-x^2}{2}})^2 dx = π\int_{-\sqrt{2}}^{\sqrt{2}} \frac{2-x^2}{2} dx= \frac {4π\sqrt{2}}{3}$

Comment: Are you looking for the proof of the formula $S=\pi ab$ ?

Comment: The Answer should be $$ \pi\ ^{2} + 2\pi\ $$

Comment: Searching for a mistake.

Answer (score 0):

$$ 2\pi\ \int_0^{\sqrt{2}} \sqrt{4-x^{2}} $$

$$ \pi \left(x \sqrt{4-x^2} + 4 * \arcsin \frac {x}{2} \right)$$

from 0 to $\sqrt{2}$ which gives $\pi^{2}$ + 2$\pi$.